# RxSwift - Observable.generate - Handle sequential requests with additional mapping

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, observable, rx-swift

**Goal**

I am trying to implement a service which downloads a file using the Range header. This allows me to download a chunk of a file at a time.

**Implementation - Observable.generate()**

In order to create an observable for each request and save the file I have tried using:

```
let downloadObservable = Observable.generate(initialState: 0, condition: { $0 < fileSize }, iterate: { $0 + self.defaultChunkSize })
```

This seems to work great! Except for larger files it seems to have an error. My requests get cancelled. After debugging I found out that my workflow doesn't work how I expected it to. Here is the rest of the workflow which is appended onto the line above.

```
.map( { (startChunk) -> (Int64, Int64) in
    // I determine the end chunk so I can download any size file in chunks of size X
    let endChunk = (startChunk + self.defaultChunkSize > fileSize ? fileSize : startChunk + self.defaultChunkSize )

    return (startChunk, endChunk)
}).flatMap( { [unowned self] (startChunk: Int64, endChunk: Int64) -> Observable<FileChunk> in
    // I make the request via alamofire - UNEXPECTED FLOW HERE SEE NOTE #1
    return self.makeChunkRequest(url: downloadUrl, startChunk: startChunk, endChunk: endChunk)

}).flatMap( { [unowned self] (fileChunk: FileChunk) -> Observable<FileSaveChunkResult> in
    // Upon receiving chunk response save to file
    return self.saveChunkToFile(fileChunk: fileChunk, location: localDestinationUrl)

}).flatMap( { (saveResult: FileSaveChunkResult) -> Observable<Progress> in
    // Update progress if successful
    switch (saveResult) {
    case .success(let bytesSaved):
        progress.completedUnitCount += bytesSaved
    case .failure:
        break
    }

    return Observable.just(progress)
})
```

**Note #1**

When I run and debug this, my first `flatMap` loops until **ALL** of the chunk requests are made. I was expecting this to be more sequential where we would generate an observable and then do all of the conversions via `flatMap` and then loop back to the beginning.

Is this not how I should be implementing it?

Do I need to do some magic with `merge()` on my `Observable.generate()`?

Comment: An answer to this one took a bit, but I found it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the solution to this question. The key is to `map` over the network requests and then `concat` them. Do this instead of using `flatMap`. The `concat` operator will wait until a request sends an onCompleted before starting the next request. Code below:

```
let downloadObservable = Observable.generate(initialState: 0, condition: { $0 < fileSize }, iterate: { $0 + self.defaultChunkSize })
    .map( { (startChunk) -> (Int64, Int64) in
        let endChunk = (startChunk + self.defaultChunkSize > fileSize ? fileSize : startChunk + self.defaultChunkSize )
        return (startChunk, endChunk)
    }).map( { [unowned self] (startChunk: Int64, endChunk: Int64) -> Observable<FileChunk> in
        return self.makeChunkRequest(url: downloadUrl, startChunk: startChunk, endChunk: endChunk)
    }).concat()
    .flatMap( { [unowned self] (fileChunk: FileChunk) -> Observable<FileSaveChunkResult> in
        return self.saveChunkToFile(fileChunk: fileChunk, location: localDestinationUrl)
    }).flatMap( { (saveResult: FileSaveChunkResult) -> Observable<Progress> in
        if case .success(let bytesSaved) = saveResult {
            progress.completedUnitCount += bytesSaved
        }
        return Observable.just(progress)
    })
```

I figured out how to chunk it up into batches of 4. I spread it out a bit and made comments in the code to help:

```
let generator = Observable.generate(initialState: 0, condition: { $0 < fileSize }, iterate: { $0 + defaultChunkSize })
let chunks  = generator.map( { (startChunk) -> (Int64, Int64) in
    let endChunk = (startChunk + defaultChunkSize > fileSize ? fileSize : startChunk + defaultChunkSize )
    return (startChunk, endChunk)
})
let requests = chunks.buffer(timeSpan: 0.0, count: 4, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)// makes batches of four item arrays.
    .map { (batch) -> Observable<FileChunk> in
        let requests = Observable.from(batch) // spreads the four items back out.
        return requests.flatMap( { (startChunk: Int64, endChunk: Int64) -> Observable<FileChunk> in
            return makeChunkRequest(url: downloadUrl, startChunk: startChunk, endChunk: endChunk)
        }) // start the four requests as normal.
    }.concat() // wait until the four requests are finished before allowing the next four to begin.

let downloadObservable = requests
    .flatMap( { (fileChunk: FileChunk) -> Observable<FileSaveChunkResult> in
        return saveChunkToFile(fileChunk: fileChunk, location: localDestinationUrl)
    }).flatMap( { (saveResult: FileSaveChunkResult) -> Observable<Progress> in
        if case .success(let bytesSaved) = saveResult {
            progress.completedUnitCount += bytesSaved
        }
        return Observable.just(progress)
    })
```

Comment: This is awesome! So one thing I learned is that my session manager in alamofire can handle up to 4 requests at a time. Using your map().concat() I indeed do one request at a time which prevents the issue I was having. However it also chops my download speed since I can only do one request at a time. Any idea how to improve this to allow 4 requests? I haven't tried getting it to do this yet so I will look at that now but figured I should reply to your answer!

Comment: You will want to use the `buffer` operator for that.

Comment: So I'll want to do something like .concat().buffer().flatMapWithIndex()? Since the buffer() is returning an array of FileChunks in this case? Sorry, not familiar with buffer at all.

Comment: Now would be a good time to make your code testable. I've only used buffer once myself so I'm not entirely sure how to set it up.

Comment: Here you go, chunked up into batches of four. The only down-side now is that the whole batch has to finish before any of the next four start...